# Why is google apps spreadsheet setValue function not setting values in cells?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Why can't I use setValues in google apps spreadsheets API to set the values of cells in a spreadsheet?

I entered the correct cell and the value seems ok. however nothing appears in the cells!
I used the following to create the rows after the first row in my sheet.

```
sheet.insertRowsAfter(1,15);
```

After which I did this

```
sheet.setActiveCell("C2").setValue("AAA");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you need to get the range before you can set values into it. Your code should be:

```
sheet.getRange("c2").setValue("AAA");
```

This difference between GAS and VBA took me a little while to get used to. You have to "get your hands on" a range before you can alter or set its values.

Answer (score -3):

I found the answer to this question my self and wanted to preventing others from having the same problem.

Google aps api will set the default font color of a new cell to what ever the color above it is. I used white on blue color for my description column. The white font color propagated but not the background resulting in white on white color. I finaly found this and corrected it by setting cell fontcolor using

`setFontColor("#000000");`

Comment: This is most probably not true... setValue sets value, not format ! so what happend is that you had a cell format with white fonts where your script set the value... there is no such thing as format propagation.

Comment: These cells were created as new cells and had white color.

Comment: maybe then you should show the code you used to 'create' these cells

Comment: I have no way of verifying if this was a bug in that version of docs so I suggest we remove this answer if it's not satisfying any one any more.